# Convert array of string or integers to comma separated integer or string for sql in condition

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

```
  public List<String> getCategory(final String logicalUnitCode, final String logicalUnitIdent, final String keyword) {
        return entityManager
                .createNativeQuery(
                        "select name from " + logicalUnitCode + " where " + keyword + "::text in(" + logicalUnitIdent + "::text)")
                .getResultList();
    }
```

In some case keyword is int8 and logicalUnitIdent is String of integers for example: ("1,2,3,4,5") , and in some cases keyword is varchar and logicalUnitIdent is string (("test,test1,test2"). I want to use one query for both of this cases. Any suggestion how can i achive that and is it possible? To cast both to text or varchar? Im using postgres

Comment: In some case keyword is Long? How a table column can be Long? It's confusing.

Comment: my bad...int8 is type of column

Comment: where keyword in(..) keyword is column name right?

Comment: yes.. keyword is for example (code that is varchar or id that is int8)

Comment: in that case before calling getCategory() you create logicalUnitIdent String and pass. Modify query to handle both string and number

Comment: logicalUnitIdent = "1,2,3" or "'string1','string2','string3'

Comment: how can i do that? logicalUnitIdent is for some cases already "1,2,3" and its working but i have a problem with strings because i dont know how to create from string "string2,string2,string3" -> "'string1','string2','string3'

Comment: Unfortunately, hibernate does not support lists, and I don’t know why - it’s needed commonly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before calling getCategory() you create logicalUnitIdent String and pass. But modify the query to `"in("+logicalUnitIdent+")"`

logicalUnitIdent should be "1,2,3" or "'string1','string2','string3'
To convert List of string to single quoted and comma separated string use the below code

In JDK 8 or above use this

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("string1","string2","string3"));
        String list= String.join(",", stringList
                .stream()
                .map(name -> ("'" + name + "'"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

System.out.println(list); // prints 'string1','string2','string3'
```